# Manipulate HTML table data with multiple form field submission in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

I've got a table of data that a user can filter using a variety of options.

I can manipulate the data with the form submission fine but the form accepts both `$_POST` variables and in some cases I want a user to only use one.

`MP | Conservative | Year Elected`

For example:

Case #1 - A user searches for 'Conservative` party but doesn't care about the year elected.

Case #2 - A user searches for '2005' year of election but doesn't care about the political party.

Case #3 - A user searches for 'Conversative' party and in '2005'.

And here's my code:

Global variables

```
if(empty($_POST['year_elec'])) {
    $year = "show_all";
} 
else {
    $year = $_POST['year_elec'];
}

if(empty($_POST['party'])) {
    $party = "show_all";
}
else {
    $party = $_POST['party'];
}
```

The main table generation:

```
        if($year == "show_all" && $party == "show_all") {
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM mps";
                    }
                    else if(!empty($year) && $party ="show_all"){
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM mps WHERE year_elec = $year";
                    }
                    else if($year == "show_all" && !empty($party)) {
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM mps WHERE party = $party";

                    }
                    else {
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM mps WHERE year_elec = $year AND party = $party";
                    }

                        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                        while ($a = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                            $name = $a['name'];
                            $party = $a['party'];
                            $consti = $a['cont'];
                            $year_elec = $a['year_elec'];

                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>" .$name. "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" .$party. "</td>";                       
                            echo "<td>" .$consti. "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" .$year_elec. "</td>";       
                            echo "</tr>";           
                        }
```

The form

```
<form method="post" action="mps.php">
            <span class="css-select-moz">
                <select name="year_elec" id="selectYear">
                    <option <?php if (isset($year) && $year=="2010") echo "selected";?> name="2010" value="2010">First elected 2010</option>
                    <option <?php if (isset($year) && $year=="2005") echo "selected";?> name="2005" value="2005">First elected 2005</option>
                    <option <?php if (isset($year) && $year=="2001") echo "selected";?> name="2001" value="2001">First elected 2001</option>
                </select>
            </span> <br />

            <span class="css-select-moz">
                <select name="party" id="selectParty">                  
                    <?php
                        $query = "SELECT DISTINCT party FROM mps";
                        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                        while($a = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                            $party = $a['party'];
                            echo "<option name='$party' value='$party'>$party</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </span>
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Load" />
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont really see a problem in your code, apart from a single `=` in your 1st `else if`.

However you can neaten things up with the ternary operator to assign values to `$year` and `$party`. And can use the not equal to operator instead of not empty:

```
$year = $_POST['year_elec']?:'show_all';
$party = $_POST['party']?:'show_all';

if($year == "show_all" && $party == "show_all") {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM mps";
}
else if($year != "show_all" && $party == "show_all"){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM mps WHERE year_elec = $year";
}
else if($year == "show_all" && $party != "show_all") {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM mps WHERE party = $party";
}
else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM mps WHERE year_elec = $year AND party = $party";
}
```

Also note that you are open to SQL injection attacks, ideally use prepared statements and a whitelist of values the use can select from (an array of political parties, and an array of dates)

Comment: Thanks for the help. You're the first person to highlight SQL injection attacks without being condescending. I'll try the tidier version of code and upvote if it works :)